# Extra blue section in popover between the navigation bar title and the view controller's view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am using UIPopoverController to present a popover from a selected UITableViewCell. The problem is that the popover title area is too tall. It appears that below the navigation bar, and above the view controller's view, there's an extra blue rounded rect appearing above the UITextView. Why is it there, and how do I get rid of it?

The popover controller's content view controller is a UINavigationController. The UINavigationController's root view controller is a UIViewController. The UIViewController's view is a UITextView.

The UIViewController sets its title property to "UIViewController title". The UITextView sets its text to "UITextView text\n\nUITextView text\n\nUITextView text". There are no other buttons or views in the popover.

Popover screenshot from my iOS simulator:

[image]

I'm using iOS 5.1, Xcode 4.3.1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: set wantsFullScreenLayout to YES in the UIViewController.